# How can I make my list stop at a certain value?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am trying to set the range of the list by the values that I give. I was able to set the head of the list and write the rest of it. However I am couldn't make the list stop at the hi value that I put in the function. How do I make my list stop at that specific value?

I tried different combinations between the conditions that I wrote. I tried putting x > hi = [] as the first condition, I thought once the next element on the list was greater than hi the list would end.

```
inRangeRec :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inRangeRec lo hi [] = []
inRangeRec lo hi (x:xs) | lo <= x && x <= hi = lo : [ x | x <- xs]
                        | otherwise          = inRangeRec lo hi xs
                        | x > hi             = []
```

I expect inRangeRec 3 5 [1..10] == [3,4,5]
but the output I get is [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: what should `inRangeRec 3 5 [10,5,1,3,9,4]` return? Should it be `[]` or `[5,3,4]`?

Comment: `[x | x <- xs]` is the same as `xs`; it's not the same `x` as the head of the list you matched. Also, `lo` may not actually be in the list, but you are adding it to the result.

Comment: `otherwise` should always go last.  Consider `if True then inRangeRec ... ; else []`.  `otherwise` literally equals `True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say is to let the value `x` if it is in range, if not, remove it, and stop if `x` is greater than max, so:

```
inRangeRec :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inRangeRec lo hi [] = []
inRangeRec lo hi xss@(x:xs) | lo <= x && x <= hi = x : inRangeRec lo hi xs
                            | x > hi             = [] 
                            | otherwise          = inRangeRec lo hi xs
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) to take elements as long as a certain condition holds.

We can here thus use `filter` and `takeWhile`, like:

```
inRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
inRange lo hi = filter (> lo) . takeWhile (< hi)
```

or in case we know that the list is in ascending order, we can use [**`dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) as well:

```
inRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
inRange lo hi = dropWhile (< lo) . takeWhile (< hi)
```